# How to read IMEI modem Qualcomm SnapDragon X55 5G on Lenovo ThinkPad X13 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, window, linux-device-driver, qualcomm

I'm doing a project where I need to display the IMEI number of X55 5G modem of Lenovo Thinkpad X13 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I need to read the IMEI number with the condition that the SIM card is not connected to the device.

I did it in the following way:

1. Install ModemManager:
   ~# sudo apt-get install -y modem-manager-gui
2. List detected modems:
   ~# mmcli --list-modems
   No modems were found

It didn't detect any 5G modem. This is not fun at all!

I found a website that talks about this problem:
https://mobile-broadband.pages.freedesktop.org/docs/modemmanager/fcc-unlock/
It said that:
"Since ModemManager 1.18.4, the following applies: The FCC unlock procedure is no longer enabled by default."
I tried unlocking it according to their instructions:
~# sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*
As a result, I still can't detect the modem.

I have consulted some ways in other forums:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Finally-X55-5G-modem-works-under-linux/m-p/5082236
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Finally-X55-5G-modem-works-under-linux/m-p/5082236?page=15
http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/wireless/modem#libqmi-firmware
https://smartsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/smart/smart-edge/thinkedge-se30/solutions/ht513558-how-to-enable-wwan-in-stock-ubuntu-thinkedge-se30
Still, nothing miraculous happened.

I want to know the following issues:

1. Can I read the IMEI without connecting to the sim card?
2. Is it possible to do FCC unlock procedure on GNU/Linux OS?

Can someone provide me with a solution to this problem?
If windows OS can I read this IMEI number from a log file or better a command?

Comment: Use lspci to detect the m.2 card vendor/model and then find the supporting driver. See if the driver provides a means to read IMEI

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Debian 12. To get the IMEI of my LTE modem, I use:

```
sudo mmcli -L
sudo mmcli -m 0
```

(where 0 is the index of the modem)